# Error al utilizar variable de session en Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estoy tratando de usar variables de session en mi aplicacion Asp.Net Mvc y me devuelve error : **No se puede usar [] para la indixazion a una expresion del tipo `Isession`**

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["nombreCompleto "] = nombreCompleto;
```

encontre esto :
*Se debe activar la Session en tu web.config al menos asi*

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"> </sessionState>
```

Mi problema es que la aplicacion usa appsettings.json como archivo de configuracion intente agregar un web.config pero me da error de ambiguedad

*¿Que puedo hacer para solucionar este problema?*

Comment: en que contexto usas `HttpContext.Current` ? porque no se usa de esa forma si accedes desde el action del controller

Comment: Exactamente la nesecito usar en un Controlador ...Como deberia usarla ?

Comment: estas usando asp.net mvc o asp.net core ? es un desarrollo con .net core?

Comment: estoy usando Asp.Net Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Habilitar la `Session` en `asp.net core` requiere algo mas que solo modificar el `.config`

[Session state](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#session-state)

como observaras se debe agregar

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });
```

y ademas

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{

    app.UseSession();
```

desde el `action` accedes usando

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save()
{

    HttpContext.Session.SetString("nombreCompleto", nombreCompleto);

}
```

Se usa los metodos `SetString()` y `GetString()`